# How do I enable dark mode on other sites in the network?

Tags: support, dark-mode

I have dark mode on Stack Overflow enabled.

How do I use dark mode on the Electrical Engineering site?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dark mode is currently in beta and only available on Stack Overflow. You cannot enable it anywhere else at this time.

Comment: It'd be nice if it wasn't announced across all the other sites then, hey?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Dark Reader](https://darkreader.org/) Chrome/Edge/Firefox/Safari extension, or natively on Chrome (chrome://flags/ : `#enable-force-dark`).