# The dark theme is not supported in communities aside from Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, user-experience, dark-mode

Is it possible to enable dark mode in the other communities aside from Stack Overflow? I find it weird when I switch to another community.

[image: switching theme interface in Stack Overflow only]

Comment: It is not...yet.  We've seen screenshots of work-in-progress on it, though.

Comment: In the meantime, https://darkreader.org/ is great.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345886/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345762/282094

Comment: Converting Stack Overflow resulting in [over 150 feedbacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/3648282), so the future is going to be limited to the Stack Overflow sites (in different languages) and their metas. They don't have access to the original files for much of the artwork on the other sites, to enable simple adjustment of the colors, to have correct contrast and readability.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this has not yet been implemented. It should be noted, though, that it is in progress (see Ryan M's comment).

Personally, I use the Dark Reader extension, which you can get on [darkreader.org](https://darkreader.org). It supports Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and MS Edge.

It has plenty of customizability, click on it in your extension bar. Plus, you can disable/enable it on separate sites.

And if you're good at CSS, it has a setting to manually change all of the CSS attributes of the extension. Heck, you could make a dark mode a lighter mode with it if you really wanted to..